# Is there a way to activate tags with osmdroid?

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am currently building an Android app for firefighters in which I am using `osmdroid` to create an editable map view. On OSM there are tags you can activate to show certain types of points of interest, and especially there are tags for firefighters (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:emergency), that seems essential for my app.

I looked at OSMbonuspack's POIs, but that only works for building types, and I didn't find an option for those in `osmdroid`.

Does anyone know of a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OSMBonusPack's [OverpassAPIProvider](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/OverpassAPIProvider) to show POIs with any tags you like. The KML example shows how to display speed cameras (`highway=speed_camera`). For showing firefighter features just replace it with `amenity=fire_station`, `emergency=fire_hydrant` or similar tags.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, I'll try that right now :)